# How do I add player parameters to a video using DevDemons Channel Videos

Tags: video, channel-videos, devdemon

I know it's possible to add parameters to a youtube url and these will load different settings.

Like this parameter **?rel=0** indicates whether the player should show related videos when playback of the initial video ends.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel

If I add a video in DevDemon Channel Videos and pass the parameter **?rel=0** it doesn't show any result(the related videos still show up). Does anyone know how to pass the parameters the right way?

Comment: The Channel Videos page says it allows "Direct URL Submission". Is this how you're currently trying to pass the parameter?

Comment: I've looked up the source code and I see the do use "Direct URL Submission" but the add a questionmark at the end.    
`<iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?rel=0?" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">`

Comment: Sounds like you need to hack the addon to remove the question mark if there isn't a place in the UI to add the parameter so it appears after their inserted question mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Channel Videos 3.1.0 introduced a Module Control Panel where you can control all of those available parameters from a central point.

There is no need to use template parameters.

[image: Channel Videos MCP]

Comment: Alright that fixed it! I was still running 3.0.3 so I didn't had new parameter options.

Answer (score 4):

I've analysed the source code of Channel Videos and saw that there was a template tag parameter available named **youtube:url_params** that does add the parameters to the video but again added the questionmark at the end.

I rewrote/hacked the code to provide a solution that if there are parameters in the direct URL they will be placed correctly without question mark. And if there are parameters in the template tag **youtube:url_params** they will be placed correctly with a question mark.

**File:** mod.channel_videos.php

**Line** 203

```
//Added a fix for placing a questionmark after a direct link with params
$extra_params = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('youtube:url_params', '');
$extra_params = !empty($extra_params) ? '?'.$extra_params : '' ; 
$vars[$prefix.'web_url'] = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $vid->service_video_id;
$vars[$prefix.'embed_code'] = "<iframe width='{$embed_width}' height='{$embed_height}' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$vid->service_video_id}{$extra_params}' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

#### Fix still needed...

> Note: The fix provided above doesn't solve the problem because it's based on the service_video_id that is extracted out off the URL in the get_video() method. When I've completed the fix I'll update it.